# UNNotificationCenter issue crash the app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios9

When I run my App on ios10 or later, the app works fine but the problem is that when I run the app on ios9 it crashes. I put deployment target 9.0 or later ,I could not find why it is not working on ios 9 and the warning shows like this :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSString
>   localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:arguments:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to class 0x10d042b00'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with method: **localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:arguments**.

Please note that this method is only **available from iOS 10+**. 
This method you are using comes in **UserNotifications** framework. This framework introduced in iOS 10. That's why it's not supporting iOS9 devices.

Please refer this document : [Apple Doc on UserNotifications Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1649585-localizedusernotificationstringf)

Comment: i wrote like this::::objNotificationContent.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Reminder Notification!" arguments:nil];

Comment: Open the given document and check right side. It's available from iOS 10+

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using localizedUserNotificationstringForKey is available for iOS 10 or later , it’s not for ios9